Docker: "no space left on device" on Jenkins master node
I'm using Docker on amazonlinux 2023 with Jenkins (non docker) installed. Everything has been working fine for a month, but today, running a Jenkins job that builds docker image and pushes to Dockerhub, I've got such an error:
ERROR: Error: Failed to build and push Dockerfile. Error Message: #0 building with "multi-platform-builder" instance using docker-container driver

#1 [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile
#1 transferring dockerfile: 422B done
#1 DONE 0.0s

#2 [auth] library/amazoncorretto:pull token for registry-1.docker.io
#2 DONE 0.0s

#3 [linux/amd64 internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/amazoncorretto:17-al2023-jdk
#3 DONE 0.1s

#4 [linux/arm64 internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/amazoncorretto:17-al2023-jdk
#4 DONE 0.2s

#5 [internal] load .dockerignore
#5 transferring context: 2B done
#5 DONE 0.0s

#6 [linux/arm64 1/4] FROM docker.io/library/amazoncorretto:17-al2023-jdk@sha256:062975d66d428abce20245971a308272a542c878ea1d73640cfb73b2f67881e7
#6 resolve docker.io/library/amazoncorretto:17-al2023-jdk@sha256:062975d66d428abce20245971a308272a542c878ea1d73640cfb73b2f67881e7 0.0s done
#6 sha256:9e9fed32a5abe858a3da59b4ae619db75667ff254ce70765c6df8e9ddc60be42 12.58MB / 155.74MB 0.2s
#6 sha256:cbddb8fcc56265c7d316c4886c5874790b5fbdc8ecff1d3b10689482ea2ef29c 12.58MB / 51.40MB 0.1s
#6 sha256:9e9fed32a5abe858a3da59b4ae619db75667ff254ce70765c6df8e9ddc60be42 27.26MB / 155.74MB 0.3s
#6 sha256:cbddb8fcc56265c7d316c4886c5874790b5fbdc8ecff1d3b10689482ea2ef29c 28.31MB / 51.40MB 0.3s
#6 ...

#7 [internal] load build context
#7 transferring context: 53.70MB 0.4s done
#7 DONE 0.6s

#6 [linux/arm64 1/4] FROM docker.io/library/amazoncorretto:17-al2023-jdk@sha256:062975d66d428abce20245971a308272a542c878ea1d73640cfb73b2f67881e7
#6 sha256:9e9fed32a5abe858a3da59b4ae619db75667ff254ce70765c6df8e9ddc60be42 35.65MB / 155.74MB 0.5s
#6 sha256:cbddb8fcc56265c7d316c4886c5874790b5fbdc8ecff1d3b10689482ea2ef29c 35.65MB / 51.40MB 0.5s
#6 DONE 0.9s

#8 [linux/amd64 1/4] FROM docker.io/library/amazoncorretto:17-al2023-jdk@sha256:062975d66d428abce20245971a308272a542c878ea1d73640cfb73b2f67881e7
#8 resolve docker.io/library/amazoncorretto:17-al2023-jdk@sha256:062975d66d428abce20245971a308272a542c878ea1d73640cfb73b2f67881e7 0.0s done
#8 sha256:e57b76530702b26c725c16381ff14709b36b0e5b187d7ec36c7a95fddf36516c 35.65MB / 157.04MB 0.8s
#8 sha256:ee5ee70789863a32f444d11d47a2849acfc6089e3e8c78d196f63475ee994293 31.98MB / 52.31MB 0.8s
#8 ...

#9 [linux/arm64 2/4] WORKDIR /opt/ignite
#9 ERROR: failed to copy: write /var/lib/buildkit/runc-overlayfs/content/ingest/691b3226e79a7b9da581dc37b27f55770a626d705a8c6d6c892b4cb237d8b385/data: no space left on device

#10 [linux/amd64 2/4] WORKDIR /opt/ignite
#10 ERROR: failed to copy: write /var/lib/buildkit/runc-overlayfs/content/ingest/bb152c084a88f3f1d253fd302e41fe6b0185f8bfe7962ac6bae981c2cea9d0c7/data: no space left on device
------
 > [linux/arm64 2/4] WORKDIR /opt/ignite:
------
------
 > [linux/amd64 2/4] WORKDIR /opt/ignite:
------
Dockerfile:5
--------------------
   3 |     
   4 |     ENV IGNITE_HOME=/opt/ignite
   5 | >>> WORKDIR /opt/ignite
   6 |     
   7 |     #RUN apk --no-cache add bash
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: failed to copy: write /var/lib/buildkit/runc-overlayfs/content/ingest/691b3226e79a7b9da581dc37b27f55770a626d705a8c6d6c892b4cb237d8b385/data: no space left on device

I'm building multiplatform image with buildx, but the problem can be reproduce with a simple 'docker build' command.
I've googled the problem and people advice just clean up docker containers, images, volumes...
But I've check free space at root volume and I did not find any space issues.
[ec2-user@ip-172-30-1-39 ~]$ df -h
Filesystem        Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs          4.0M     0  4.0M   0% /dev
tmpfs              16G     0   16G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs             6.2G  756K  6.2G   1% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p1     20G  5.3G   15G  27% /
tmpfs              16G  1.1G   15G   7% /tmp
/dev/nvme0n1p128   10M  1.3M  8.7M  13% /boot/efi
/dev/nvme1n1      196G   75G  112G  41% /var/lib/jenkins
tmpfs             3.1G     0  3.1G   0% /run/user/1000

As you see / root volume has 15G available. I've also tried to change Docker Root Directory to an EBS Volume where my Jenkins's data is stored -> /dev/nvme1n1 (112G available) via /etc/docker/daemon.json.
[ec2-user@ip-172-30-1-39 ~]$ cat /etc/docker/daemon.json
{
  "data-root": "/var/lib/jenkins/docker"
}

But it didn't help to solve the problem.
I've also deleted docker and its related data and reinstall it, but it still gives the same problem.
NOTE: Interesting thing that I have 2 differe Jenkins jobs that build Dockerimages, and one of them can succeed while the other one no, or vice versa.
Here is DockerFiles:
Dockerfile #1:
FROM amazoncorretto:17-al2023-jdk

ENV IGNITE_HOME=/opt/ignite
WORKDIR /opt/ignite

#RUN apk --no-cache add bash

COPY assembly/lib lib
COPY assembly/im-be-server*.jar im-be-server.jar

EXPOSE 11211 47100 47500 49112 10800 8080

CMD ["sh", "-c", "java $JAVA_OPTIONS -jar im-be-server.jar"]

Dockerfile #2:
FROM amazoncorretto:17-al2023-jdk
WORKDIR /opt/im-be
COPY im-be-client*.war ./im-be-client.war

CMD ["sh", "-c", "java $JAVA_OPTIONS -jar im-be-client.war"]

Based on Error output, I've tried to find /var/lib/buildkit... but there is no such directory in filesystem.
PS: Here is my code that I use to build docker image, maybe there is something wrong with it?
try {
        infoSh 'docker ps -a'
        info "Start building Docker Image: ${imageName}:${imageTag} from Dockerfile: ${dockerfile} in Working Directory: ${workDir}"
        sh "echo ${password} | docker login -u ${username} --password-stdin 2>error.log"
        sh "docker buildx build --push --platform linux/amd64,linux/arm64 -t ${imageName}:${imageTag} -f ${dockerfile} ${workDir} 2>error.log"
    } catch (Exception e) {
        error "Error: Failed to build and push Dockerfile. Error Message: ${readFile('error.log').trim()}"
        throw e
    } finally {
        info '''Cleaning up Docker resources:
            - all stopped containers
            - all networks not used by at least one container
            - all volumes not used by at least one container
            - all dangling images
            - all build cache  
        '''
        sh 'docker system prune --volumes -f'
    }

As you see in the end I always clean docker up. Is it correct way?
Here is also Error for commond docker build (without multiarch):
docker build -t test docker/im-be-server
#0 building with "default" instance using docker driver

#1 [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile
#1 transferring dockerfile: 423B done
#1 DONE 0.0s

#2 [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/amazoncorretto:17-alpine-jdk
#2 DONE 0.1s

#3 [internal] load .dockerignore
#3 transferring context: 2B done
#3 DONE 0.0s

#4 [internal] load build context
#4 transferring context: 8.76kB done
#4 DONE 0.0s

#5 [1/4] FROM docker.io/library/amazoncorretto:17-alpine-jdk@sha256:950933535cc7d81fe0851e6b4782f4b25b24a9e3115bbacc77b40c57144701c0
#5 resolve docker.io/library/amazoncorretto:17-alpine-jdk@sha256:950933535cc7d81fe0851e6b4782f4b25b24a9e3115bbacc77b40c57144701c0 0.0s done
#5 extracting sha256:b84a74cde5af5c5199bfc2ce2a8c8951a29a7716d17327e923f1a14c870a858b
#5 extracting sha256:b84a74cde5af5c5199bfc2ce2a8c8951a29a7716d17327e923f1a14c870a858b 0.1s done
#5 sha256:0e763fa4969988d8cf0a53b7471be64a8c38b1d81d2bd89f362d387565791a25 1.37kB / 1.37kB done
#5 sha256:60d459aa3f206c915cdc2beb55f50efe372bac2a8eff2038ab034003c51d28cb 2.38kB / 2.38kB done
#5 sha256:b84a74cde5af5c5199bfc2ce2a8c8951a29a7716d17327e923f1a14c870a858b 3.42MB / 3.42MB 0.1s done
#5 sha256:b0db5f63c3906482ac90304cf0e89c91fc810984dd49f92dd3a9d8ab4b99878b 5.24MB / 146.24MB 0.2s
#5 sha256:950933535cc7d81fe0851e6b4782f4b25b24a9e3115bbacc77b40c57144701c0 2.67kB / 2.67kB done
#5 sha256:b0db5f63c3906482ac90304cf0e89c91fc810984dd49f92dd3a9d8ab4b99878b 26.21MB / 146.24MB 0.3s
#5 sha256:b0db5f63c3906482ac90304cf0e89c91fc810984dd49f92dd3a9d8ab4b99878b 37.75MB / 146.24MB 0.4s
#5 sha256:b0db5f63c3906482ac90304cf0e89c91fc810984dd49f92dd3a9d8ab4b99878b 56.62MB / 146.24MB 0.6s
#5 sha256:b0db5f63c3906482ac90304cf0e89c91fc810984dd49f92dd3a9d8ab4b99878b 76.55MB / 146.24MB 0.8s
#5 sha256:b0db5f63c3906482ac90304cf0e89c91fc810984dd49f92dd3a9d8ab4b99878b 96.47MB / 146.24MB 1.0s
#5 sha256:b0db5f63c3906482ac90304cf0e89c91fc810984dd49f92dd3a9d8ab4b99878b 113.25MB / 146.24MB 1.2s
#5 sha256:b0db5f63c3906482ac90304cf0e89c91fc810984dd49f92dd3a9d8ab4b99878b 127.93MB / 146.24MB 1.3s
#5 sha256:b0db5f63c3906482ac90304cf0e89c91fc810984dd49f92dd3a9d8ab4b99878b 1.05MB / 146.24MB 6.9s
#5 sha256:b0db5f63c3906482ac90304cf0e89c91fc810984dd49f92dd3a9d8ab4b99878b 12.58MB / 146.24MB 7.0s
#5 sha256:b0db5f63c3906482ac90304cf0e89c91fc810984dd49f92dd3a9d8ab4b99878b 32.51MB / 146.24MB 7.2s
#5 sha256:b0db5f63c3906482ac90304cf0e89c91fc810984dd49f92dd3a9d8ab4b99878b 41.94MB / 146.24MB 7.3s
#5 sha256:b0db5f63c3906482ac90304cf0e89c91fc810984dd49f92dd3a9d8ab4b99878b 61.87MB / 146.24MB 7.5s
#5 sha256:b0db5f63c3906482ac90304cf0e89c91fc810984dd49f92dd3a9d8ab4b99878b 81.79MB / 146.24MB 7.7s
#5 sha256:b0db5f63c3906482ac90304cf0e89c91fc810984dd49f92dd3a9d8ab4b99878b 99.61MB / 146.24MB 7.9s
#5 sha256:b0db5f63c3906482ac90304cf0e89c91fc810984dd49f92dd3a9d8ab4b99878b 122.68MB / 146.24MB 8.1s
#5 sha256:b0db5f63c3906482ac90304cf0e89c91fc810984dd49f92dd3a9d8ab4b99878b 130.02MB / 146.24MB 8.5s
#5 sha256:b0db5f63c3906482ac90304cf0e89c91fc810984dd49f92dd3a9d8ab4b99878b 0B / 146.24MB 18.6s
#5 sha256:b0db5f63c3906482ac90304cf0e89c91fc810984dd49f92dd3a9d8ab4b99878b 14.68MB / 146.24MB 18.7s
#5 sha256:b0db5f63c3906482ac90304cf0e89c91fc810984dd49f92dd3a9d8ab4b99878b 24.12MB / 146.24MB 18.8s
#5 sha256:b0db5f63c3906482ac90304cf0e89c91fc810984dd49f92dd3a9d8ab4b99878b 44.04MB / 146.24MB 19.0s
#5 sha256:b0db5f63c3906482ac90304cf0e89c91fc810984dd49f92dd3a9d8ab4b99878b 63.96MB / 146.24MB 19.2s
#5 sha256:b0db5f63c3906482ac90304cf0e89c91fc810984dd49f92dd3a9d8ab4b99878b 74.45MB / 146.24MB 19.3s
#5 sha256:b0db5f63c3906482ac90304cf0e89c91fc810984dd49f92dd3a9d8ab4b99878b 94.37MB / 146.24MB 19.5s
#5 sha256:b0db5f63c3906482ac90304cf0e89c91fc810984dd49f92dd3a9d8ab4b99878b 104.86MB / 146.24MB 19.6s
#5 sha256:b0db5f63c3906482ac90304cf0e89c91fc810984dd49f92dd3a9d8ab4b99878b 124.78MB / 146.24MB 19.8s
#5 sha256:b0db5f63c3906482ac90304cf0e89c91fc810984dd49f92dd3a9d8ab4b99878b 3.15MB / 146.24MB 35.4s
#5 sha256:b0db5f63c3906482ac90304cf0e89c91fc810984dd49f92dd3a9d8ab4b99878b 25.17MB / 146.24MB 35.6s
#5 sha256:b0db5f63c3906482ac90304cf0e89c91fc810984dd49f92dd3a9d8ab4b99878b 45.09MB / 146.24MB 35.8s
#5 sha256:b0db5f63c3906482ac90304cf0e89c91fc810984dd49f92dd3a9d8ab4b99878b 65.01MB / 146.24MB 36.0s
#5 sha256:b0db5f63c3906482ac90304cf0e89c91fc810984dd49f92dd3a9d8ab4b99878b 74.45MB / 146.24MB 36.1s
#5 sha256:b0db5f63c3906482ac90304cf0e89c91fc810984dd49f92dd3a9d8ab4b99878b 94.37MB / 146.24MB 36.3s
#5 sha256:b0db5f63c3906482ac90304cf0e89c91fc810984dd49f92dd3a9d8ab4b99878b 115.34MB / 146.24MB 36.5s
#5 sha256:b0db5f63c3906482ac90304cf0e89c91fc810984dd49f92dd3a9d8ab4b99878b 129.50MB / 146.24MB 36.7s
#5 sha256:b0db5f63c3906482ac90304cf0e89c91fc810984dd49f92dd3a9d8ab4b99878b 2.10MB / 146.24MB 57.1s
#5 sha256:b0db5f63c3906482ac90304cf0e89c91fc810984dd49f92dd3a9d8ab4b99878b 24.12MB / 146.24MB 57.3s
#5 sha256:b0db5f63c3906482ac90304cf0e89c91fc810984dd49f92dd3a9d8ab4b99878b 44.04MB / 146.24MB 57.5s
#5 sha256:b0db5f63c3906482ac90304cf0e89c91fc810984dd49f92dd3a9d8ab4b99878b 53.48MB / 146.24MB 57.6s
#5 sha256:b0db5f63c3906482ac90304cf0e89c91fc810984dd49f92dd3a9d8ab4b99878b 74.45MB / 146.24MB 57.8s
#5 sha256:b0db5f63c3906482ac90304cf0e89c91fc810984dd49f92dd3a9d8ab4b99878b 94.37MB / 146.24MB 58.0s
#5 sha256:b0db5f63c3906482ac90304cf0e89c91fc810984dd49f92dd3a9d8ab4b99878b 114.29MB / 146.24MB 58.2s
#5 sha256:b0db5f63c3906482ac90304cf0e89c91fc810984dd49f92dd3a9d8ab4b99878b 128.97MB / 146.24MB 58.4s
#5 ERROR: failed to copy: write /var/lib/docker/buildkit/content/ingest/367a74b96260cd3a1fcdf490cc206b4694ece280c097d750c2857e14522310dc/data: no space left on device
------
 > [1/4] FROM docker.io/library/amazoncorretto:17-alpine-jdk@sha256:950933535cc7d81fe0851e6b4782f4b25b24a9e3115bbacc77b40c57144701c0:
------
Dockerfile:1
--------------------
   1 | >>> FROM amazoncorretto:17-alpine-jdk
   2 |     
   3 |     
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: failed to copy: write /var/lib/docker/buildkit/content/ingest/367a74b96260cd3a1fcdf490cc206b4694ece280c097d750c2857e14522310dc/data: no space left on device

Here is docker info:
[ec2-user@ip-172-30-1-39 ~]$ docker info
Client:
 Version:    25.0.3
 Context:    default
 Debug Mode: false
 Plugins:
  buildx: Docker Buildx (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  v0.0.0+unknown
    Path:     /usr/libexec/docker/cli-plugins/docker-buildx

Server:
 Containers: 1
  Running: 1
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 0
 Images: 1
 Server Version: 25.0.3
 Storage Driver: overlay2
  Backing Filesystem: extfs
  Supports d_type: true
  Using metacopy: false
  Native Overlay Diff: true
  userxattr: false
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: systemd
 Cgroup Version: 2
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Runtimes: io.containerd.runc.v2 runc
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: 64b8a811b07ba6288238eefc14d898ee0b5b99ba
 runc version: 4bccb38cc9cf198d52bebf2b3a90cd14e7af8c06
 init version: de40ad0
 Security Options:
  seccomp
   Profile: builtin
  cgroupns
 Kernel Version: 6.1.92-99.174.amzn2023.x86_64
 Operating System: Amazon Linux 2023.4.20240611
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 4
 Total Memory: 30.81GiB
 Name: ip-172-30-1-39.ec2.internal
 ID: b19b349a-445e-43fd-8458-a77d3ac6c191
 Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/jenkins/docker
 Debug Mode: false
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false

Here is also available inodes:
[ec2-user@ip-172-30-1-39 ~]$ df -ih
Filesystem       Inodes IUsed IFree IUse% Mounted on
devtmpfs           3.9M   359  3.9M    1% /dev
tmpfs              3.9M     1  3.9M    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs              800K   693  800K    1% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p1      10M   78K   10M    1% /
tmpfs              1.0M  5.6K 1019K    1% /tmp
/dev/nvme0n1p128      0     0     0     - /boot/efi
/dev/nvme1n1        13M  1.5M   12M   12% /var/lib/jenkins
tmpfs              789K    16  789K    1% /run/user/1000

How can I solve it? May be I'm doing something wrong. I'm open to answer you question or show additional information if necessary.

Does your Jenkins have any agents? Or everything runs on the same "built-in/master" agent?

My Jenkins does have agent, but it's separated one (EC2-agent) that is running on separate Node

Does this pipeline run on that separate agent?

I don't think you are looking at the "right space" if you are running docker; you need to look at the contents of the space within the docker volume; docker system df or docker system df -v.
You could try purging the images (docker rmi -f ...), but more likely you need to allocate more space.

It's just return that I have 1 image (200MB), 1 container, 1 volume (2 GB). But I have more than 15 GB available

Not sure that you have the space you think ... It regularly happened to us till we figured it out. Your docker instance only gets a portion of the volume it's mounted on. Update your Q w/ docker system df info.  Or you could be out of inodes (unlikely). YMMV
